Selenium Clicking Button Element is not clickable at point Error
CoinPoker Leaderboard Page
I want to click yesterday button to copy yesterday's data, but receveing an error doing so
My goal is to be able to click both Yestarday button and parse data located below after clicking button.
Error
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50944/devtools/browser/3fb9b8ce-215c-405f-918c-8e232e4f7379
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programowanie_new\coin_poker_lb\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    click_button.click()
  File "C:\Users\pkuzi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\pkuzi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pkuzi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\pkuzi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1151, 1563)

Code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://coinpoker.com/promotions/daily-cosmic-spins-leaderboard/")

click_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/article/div/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/button"))
)

click_button.click()

This also does not work
click_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text() = 'Yesterday']")


In this case you'll need to emulate the "click" action with JavaScript.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://coinpoker.com/promotions/daily-cosmic-spins-leaderboard/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=true")

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.nav-link[aria-selected='false']"
    for button in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(selector)):
        if button.text == "Yesterday":
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)


Thanks it works ! I managed to get all text I wanted.
I wonder though why I cannot use normal selenium because chrome extension Selenium IDE works fin with values I provided.
Is it because dynamically loaded content we have to stick to JS ?

@KurczakChrupiacy2 See this Stackoverflow question

You can try to get button by text Yesterday
...
try:
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Yesterday']")
    button.click()
    print("Button clicked!")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
...


I get such error 'Error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[normalize-space()='Yesterday']"}'
